# Make the labels on the edges of a decision tree centered/aligned

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, labels

I am trying to create a decision tree and make the labels on the edges aligned. However, as shown in the following picture, the labels on the two edges are not on the same level. I tried to use `pos=0.5` and `midway` options to fix this, but apparently this does not work. Could someone help me with that?

```
\tikzset{
  treenode/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners,
draw, align=center,
%top color=white, bottom color=blue!20
  },
  dummy/.style    = {circle,draw},
  payoff/.style    = {align=center}
}


\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
%grow                    = right,
sibling distance        = 10em,
level distance          = 4em,
edge from parent/.style = {draw},
every node/.style       = {font=\footnotesize},
%sloped
  ]
  \node [treenode] {A}
  child { node [payoff] {2\\2\\0}
  edge from parent node [above,pos=0.5] {$b=0$} }
  child { node [treenode] {B}
  child { node [payoff] {0\\2\\0}
  edge from parent node [above,pos=0.5] {R} }
  child { node [payoff] {2b\\2b\\-5b} 
  edge from parent node [above,pos=0.5] {A}
}
edge from parent node [above] {$b \ne 0$}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Please always post compilable code. It helps to ensure you get useful answers and encourages responses by making it easier to answer.

Comment: For the tree, just use `forest` ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** Currently, I've been seeing a few other questions about tree making with TikZ. Seems that there is a far more powerful package (but since it's based on TikZ could be made as a library IMHO) to do these kind of drawings: [the `forest` package](http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/tex/graphics/pgf/contrib/forest/forest-doc.pdf). And indeed, with it the syntax is a bit easier and the output consumes, nearly always, less space, take a look:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
    treenode/.style = {rounded corners, draw, base=top},
    payoff/.style   = {align=center, base=top}
    }
\begin{document}
  \begin{forest}
  %for tree={l sep=1cm, s sep=1cm},
  for tree={child anchor=north}
    [A,treenode
      [{2\\2\\0}, payoff, edge label={node[midway,left,font=\scriptsize]{$b=0$}}]
      [B,treenode,edge label={node[midway,right,font=\scriptsize]{$b\neq 0$}}
        [{0\\2\\0}, payoff, edge label={node[midway, left, font=\scriptsize]{R}}]
        [{2b\\2b\\-5b}, payoff, edge label={node[midway, right, font=\scriptsize]{A}}]
      ]
    ]
  \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: Tree with forest]

As you can see, **much** less space. Although in this case shrinking the tree too much does not look too nice, but fear not as it is possible to control the space. Uncomment the line `for tree={l sep=1cm, s sep=1cm},` to get better results and Change the `s sep` value to mess with the parent-child distance and the `l sep` for sibling distance.

---

Since the `payoff` nodes are not exactly the same size neither are the lines that connect them with the parent nodes. If you make them have the same width then all will be fine. To do so, as there is no `maximum width` option, we use the `text width` one (I also took the liberty of creating a style for the left and right side `edge` nodes, which you can alter if needed be):

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\tikzset{
  treenode/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners,
draw, align=center,
%top color=white, bottom color=blue!20
  },
  payoff/.style    = {align=center, inner sep=0.1em, text width=1.5em},
  left side node/.style={above left, inner sep=0.1em},
  right side node/.style={above right, inner sep=0.1em}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
%grow                    = right,
sibling distance        = 10em,
level distance          = 4em,
every node/.style       = {font=\footnotesize},
%sloped
  ]
  \node [treenode] {A} child{node[payoff] {2\\2\\0} edge from parent node[left side node] {$b=0$}}
                       child{node [treenode] {B} 
                                child{ node [payoff] {0\\2\\0} edge from parent node[left side node] {R}}
                                child{ node [payoff] {2b\\2b\\-5b} edge from parent node[right side node] {A}}
                                edge from parent node[right side node] {$b\neq0$}
                                };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]